# Spring 5 , Tomcat 9, Getting Error: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Tags: spring, tomcat, classpath

I am new to Spring and web applications, and trying to learn, I created a sample app in Spring5, the code compiles fine and my tests pass in Eclipse, but when I try to deploy this war under Tomcat and try to access the app I get 404 with below message in the tomcat log, I went through multiple threads reporting similar issue, but it's not working for me, where am I going wrong?

> ERROR
>
> 23-Jul-2018 23:53:01.420 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>
> Jul-2018 23:53:01.807 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">   

<display-name>yess</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:persistence-beans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My persistence-beans.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- package to look for annotated classes -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yess.web.rest, com.yess.engine" />

<context:annotation-config />
<!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- data source for our database -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample_db" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.yess.engine.domain.Sales</value>
            <value>com.yess.engine.domain.ResponsiblePerson</value>
            <value>com.yess.engine.domain.results.FinancialResults</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 
</beans>
```

and controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/scorecard")
public class ScoreCardController {

public SalesResultsService salesResultService;

/**
 * @param salesResultService
 *            the salesResultService to set
 */

@Autowired
public void setSalesResultService(SalesResultsService salesResultService) {
    this.salesResultService = salesResultService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/matrix/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<FinancialResults> getFinancialResults(@PathVariable(value = "type") String type,
        @RequestParam(value = "fromDate") LocalDate fromDate, @RequestParam(value = "toDate") LocalDate toDate)
        throws Exception {

    List<FinancialResults> results = salesResultService.getSalesResultsListByDates(fromDate, toDate);

    return results;
}

}
```

Comment: It isn't an error it is an information message. There is nothing wrong with your application, or at least that isn't related to why your application isn't starting.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, this was problem with my jsp file location